# Command Injection by breaking out from single quotes. Is it possible?

Tags: linux, command, code-injection

```
#define BUFSIZE 256

int escape_single_quotes(char *to, char *from, int max)
{  int l= 0;

  for (;*from;from++)
  {
    switch (*from)    {
      case '\'':
        if (l>=max-4) return 0; // not enough space for escaped chars!
// replace ' with '\''
        *(to++)= '\'';       
        *(to++)= '\\';
        *(to++)= '\'';
        l += 3;
      default:
        if (l>=max-1) return 0; // not enough space for this char!       
        *(to++)= *from;
        l++;
    }
  }
   *to= 0;

  return 1;
}
 int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  FILE *fp;
  char buf[BUFSIZE];
  char escaped_name[BUFSIZE];  char *filename;
  int lines, chars, cpl;


   if (argc != 2)
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s filename\n", argv[0]);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }  
  filename= argv[1];
  printf("Counting %s ... \n", filename);

  if (!escape_single_quotes(escaped_name, filename, BUFSIZE))  {
    fprintf(stderr, "Escaped filename is too long!\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
   if (snprintf(buf, BUFSIZE, "wc -l '%s'", escaped_name)>=BUFSIZE)
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "Filename %s is too long!\n", filename);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  } 
  fp= popen(buf, "r");}
```

Is this script safe from command injection? It replaces ' by '\''. Is there anyway to break from single quotes and inject a command?

Comment: This is not a script, but a C program. It appears to be executing something external. If that external cannot be trusted, then there is no point in trying to safeguard it

Comment: sorry I have a habit of calling every code snippet a script. Anyway, here the external thing is enclosed with single quotes so all I am asking is whether there is a way to break from it.

Comment: The proper, conventional fix is to replace `popen` with a safe version which does not invoke a shell. Without a shell, file names are just file names, so not an attack vector (in any straightforward fashion, anyway; and if there is a vulnerability, it is much easier to fix).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I read this program correctly, it simply calls `wc -l` on its filename parameter.

When you are trying to escape this filename, it probably means it comes from source that you cannot trust.

Given that, few points:

- Rather than that painfully escaping filename, you can simply check if such filename exists using `access()` call, and if it does, you can pass it to wc without much concern.
- I would not trust even whoever calls this very program, which means you cannot trust your own PATH. In other words, when you call `wc -l`, you may very will be calling something evil, because somebody did something along these lines:

  ```
  cp evilwc /tmp/wc
  export PATH=/tmp:$PATH
  ./yourprogram goodfilename
  ```

Oops! Even if file name was good, attacker still was able to trick your program to calling evil code.

**Solutions:**

In this particular case, you can probably implement `wc -l` on your own and not call anything external - it is very simple algorithm after all.

Also, when calling external programs, you should try to call them by full name, like `/usr/bin/wc`.

If parameters are filenames, it is good idea to check if they actually exist before passing them over.

You *may* want to sanitize your parameters for valid chars, but this is easy to do wrong, and for example remove non-ASCII symbols that are crucial for all non-English speaking world.

Comment: thanks alot!! yeah just wc command is not dependable. /usr/bin/wc must it be